# Continuous scrolling of background sprite synchronising with a moving sprite in andEngine

Tags: android, sprite, andengine

> I am new in andengine game Development. I am trying to make a game where a playerSprite moves forward and backward through X- axis. How can I continuously move the background along with the playerSprite ? If the player goes forward , the background will go forward and will repeat itself continuously . Same for moving the playerSprite to backward. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is ParalaxBackground. Here is simple example:

```
 private void createBackground()
{
ParallaxBackground background = new ParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0);
background.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0, new Sprite(0, 0, background_region, vbo)));
scene.setBackground(background);
}
```

It is from Matim-Dev andEngine Tutorial: [Matim-Dev tutorial](http://www.matim-dev.com/creating-background.html)

You might also look into sample code for AutoParalaxBackground: [AutoParalaxBackground](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/AutoParallaxBackgroundExample.java)

Comment: I have tried this , But at the second line the error   "The method attachParallaxEntity(ParallaxBackground.ParallaxEntity) in the type ParallaxBackground is not applicable for the arguments (ParallaxLayer.ParallaxEntity)"  is showing :(